# Minimization with two functions that are not completely related

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Two caveats: 1) This is a problem I formulated myself, and so may not be structured correctly/logically. 2) I don't have an extensive math background, but am currently finishing up Calc 3.

I have an objective function f(x,y,z) = x(437 + 16.28y + 24.42z) that represents the monthly cost of an agent in the contact center at my firm, where x is the number of agents, 437 is an approximation of the fixed cost per employee, y is the number of monthly hours worked, and z is the number of overtime hours worked. This cost should be minimized, subject to: the probability that any phone call being answered in greater than 30 seconds is less than 10%.

This probability relies partially on the Erlang-C function, (E^x/x! - x/x-E) / (x*E^x/x!(x-E) + summation from i = 0 to x-1 of x^i/i!) where E is the offered traffic.

The probability expression is a function of several variables, only one of which appears in the objective function.

My questions are:

1) how do I actually find critical values if the constraint function and the objective function don't have the same variables? If I hold big E (offered traffic) constant, the probability calculation is really only a function of one value, x, which is in my objective function. Can I therefore just take the probability function and set that equal to zero and use the resulting value of x as the x-value in the original function? Do I have to do a partial with respect to x of the second function? It seems this would lead to an inconclusive second-partials test (d would = 0)

2) I've understood from this forum that the Gamma function is the continuous analog of the factorial function, but assuming I can use that if I do have to do any differentiation on the probability function, how would it work inside of the summation?

3) Is optimization different for discrete variables? x (number of agents) obviously has to be an integer...

Any and all help, including pointing me in the direction of some reading/problem sets, would be sincerely appreciated.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Ozo. I'm not terribly familiar, but have read the chapter in the Larson text and watched the lectures on MIT Opencourseware after your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just re-read the question and Lagrange multipliers don't appear necessary after all (sorry).

Your objective function is minimised when $x$ is as small as possible. So if $x$ is the same in both $f$ and the Erlang-C then the question becomes: what is the smallest $x$ for which the Erlang-C function is less than 10%? Since $x$ is discrete, the easiest solution is simply to iterate over $x=1,2,...$ until you find the first value with Erlang-C < 10%. Would that be a satisfactory solution?

Comment: Ozo, that's actually how I solved it previously, but I was hoping for an analytical solution (forgive terminology if it isn't correct)